# 3D conformal mappings

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Are there analogues to conformal mapping in 3 dimensions?

I have a specific example I am trying to solve.. Laplace's equation in 3D with slightly complicated rectilinear boundaries. (Think of solving a harmonic function over a 3D boundary which is a cube but with a sub-cube "bitten" out of one corner.)

Laplace's equation is still valid under conformal transformations, so for example in 2D I could take a square domain with a subsquare bitten out of a corner, and apply an inverse tranformation [like some of these](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ConformalMapDictionary.3.html) and solve the equation in a simple square domain.

Are there similar conformal-like transformations in 3D? Perhaps they wouldn't be called conformal maps, but maybe something exists which would work similarly for my 3D Laplace equations.

Comment: Well, there are conformal map in higher dimensions (defined by saying that they preserve angles).  However, they are quite a bit less flexible than in 2d; see my answer to the following question : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10066/conformal-maps-in-higher-dimensions/10068#10068

Comment: Can I requestion "complicated" rather than "complex" in the second paragraph?  The word "complex" has all sorts of technical meaning.

Comment: Theo, you're right.. done!

Comment: Andy, yes, those affine transforms aren't useful for this. So the question stands.. are there other transforms that DO work in 3D for the Laplace equation?  Or is that really EQUIVALENT to a conformal map, meaning that only affine transforms have that characteristic in 3D?

Comment: @MathGeek: note that higher-dimensional conformal maps are not all affine, they are slightly more general than that (restriction of Möbius transform on the sphere), but this does not help for your original question.

Comment: Note that if you want to calculate the electric field in three dimensions, the size of the charges are different in the mapped region and in the region it is mapped to. This is to make up for the fact that the electric field (which is the negative gradient of the potential) scales as $s^{-1}$, where $s$ is the local scaling factor, whereas the area of a closed surface (in three dimensions) scales as $s^2$, so the total electric flux out through a surface scales as $s$. Charges therefore have to be scaled down as $s^{-1}$ to compensate for this. This problem doesn't exist in two dimensions.

Comment: I am working on a similar problem. However, my domain is possibly simpler than yours. It is a infinite plate. Have you made any progress based on three dimensional conformal mapping?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is relevant for your question...

In http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.5464v2,
the author introduces a notion of "weak conformal map" for 3-dimensional domains,
and proves a Riemann mapping theorem for those kinds of maps.

**Definition:** given two open subsets $U,V\subset \mathbb R^3$, a smooth map $f:U\to V$ is called weak conformal if, at every $x\in U$, the three eigenvalues of $P_x:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ are in geometric progression.
Here, the positive operator $P_x$ is the one coming from the polar decomposition of the tangent map $T_xf:T_x \mathbb R^3 = \mathbb R^3\to T_{f(x)} \mathbb R^3 = \mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 4):

(If I understand the question correctly) there is a theorem by Liouville stating that starting from dimension 3 the only conformal transformations are the (analogs of) the Möbius ones - composites of reflections in hyperspheres and hyperplanes. It is e. g. in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Higher-dimensional_Euclidean_space). ([Separate Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)))

There are more general quasiconformal maps, maybe they are useful here, this I don't know.

PS Just notices that this has been already said in comments to the OP actually, so I probably do not deserve these upvotes...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a 'classic' of evaluation of numerical methods. I presume the analytic answer is know.
Of course the 3D conformal mapping of your problem exist. Notably, solving the Laplacian problem of potential! :\ I used the concept to map very complex bodies in an sphere. (For fun). Of course of the same topology. I recommend to you "Calculation of potential flow about arbitrary bodies" Hess & Smith (1969?) and Kellogg "foundation of potential theory" (1929) (if you have a lot of time!). Remember. If you follow the conditions for a Laplacian fluid you can find (I do not how analytically) a mapping.
it's a very beautiful problem. The natural answer exist and it mock us.
A classic mathematical problem like "It shows that if you can transform a duck and an orange the problem has a solution and you have found it".
Now. Again a SQUARE domain? What is the joke?

Maybe you could try a somewhat different problem. To transform a cylinder inside other in a sphere inside other sphere. Now, you have a 2D problem. Singularity even exist (I assume you want to try some numerical procedure) and the problem can be mapped. 
If your problem is to evaluate a gridded domain method (like FD, FV or FE). maybe you can try an integral method. Of course. There is a problem in the singular point but if aren't nonlinearities the method is powerful.

Sorry for my very bad English. Here is 3.30am and I just have finish my drink. And. I'm not a mathematician. Only an unemployed aircraft mechanic.