# Is it possible to write down the explicit expressions of some extensions of conformal vector fields on spheres?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let X be a conformal vector field on the standard sphere $S^n$ with standard metric $g_{S^n}$, then there  exists a unique conformal vector fields in the unit ball $B_1(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, such that $Y|_{S^n}=X$. As we know, the vector fields $X=\nabla_{g_{S^n}}x^i,1\leq i\leq n+1$ are conformal on $(S^n,g_{S^n})$, where $x^i$ are coordinate functions. Then, is it possible to write down the explicit expressions of such extensions $Y$ for such conformal vector fields $X$ on spheres?

Comment: Does "conformal vector field" mean the flow is conformal?  If so, then yes they have closed form.  The group of conformal diffeos is finite-dimensional and has a well-understood description as a matrix group.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60687/the-conformal-group-of-sn?rq=1

Comment: @njucxz: $X$ is the projection of the gradient of $x_i$ w.r.t. the standard metric of $R^{n+1}$ to the unit sphere, isn'it?. Such gradients are the vectors $e_1,e_2,....,e_{n+1}$ of the canonical orthonormal frame. Are you asking how to project such constant vector fields to the unit sphere?

Comment: @ Holonomai Not yet! The gradient $x^i$ is with respect to the standard spherical metric.

Comment: @njucxz and such gradient is the orthogonal projection of the gradient of $x^i$ w.r.t. the standard metric of $R^{n+1}$ . So you are indeed asking how to project vectors form the ambient Euclidean space to the sphere.

Comment: @ Holonomia I think both are the same.

Comment: For the above explicit conformal vector fields on sphere, I am very curious about what is the explicit expressions of such conformal vector fields in the unit ball. As we know, the conformal group is clear for Eclidean space. Another question which I want to ask is that for any smooth compact manifold with boundary, how to extend the conformal vector fields on the boundary to the ones in the whole manifold? Can we solve it by some system of PDEs?

Comment: Yes, it can be explicitly written down. Define 
$$\Phi(x)=(x\cdot e_{n+1})x-\frac{1}{2}(1+|x|^2)e_{n+1}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$$ Then $\Phi(x)$ is a conformal vector field in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\Phi(x)|_{S^n}=-\nabla_{S^n}x^{n+1}$.